# Error Handling + Extracting space-separated float values from a string?

Tags: c

I have a string file_string that uses the function fgets to make a string from a text file. This file could contain up to 10,000 floating point values, though it also has to handle bad values (such as 12.e, or 4e.3) by setting those values to -1000. I want to loop through the list and do this, but I am really struggling to find a method that works.

Currently, I tried to use fscanf while knowing how many values, but that doesn't seem to work either (wrong # of values getting computed, not recording data properly).

Here is the code snippet:

```
char file_string[50000];
fgets(file_string, 50000, fp);
float data[10000];
int count = 0;
int i;
int space=1;
i=0;
while(i<=file_string[i]){
    if(file_string[i]==' '){
        space++;
    }
    i++;
}
printf("File: %s\n", file_string);
printf("Spaces: %d\n", space);
while (count < space) {
    if (data[count] = fscanf(fp, "%f")) {
        printf("Data added: %f\n", data[count]);
    }
    else {
        data[count] = -1000;
        printf("Data added: %f\n", data[count]);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Any ideas? I also tried a sscanf implementation, but that did not seem to work either.

Thanks!

Comment: `strtod()` was custom made for this purpose. There are many examples of `strtol()` and `strtod()` on this site. See also [strtod(3) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I will check that out- thanks. New to C, has been challenging

Comment: You will fill your string with a number of floats using `fgets()`. Then you will use `strtod()` with the string as `nptr` and a second pointer to use as `endptr` (see man page). A call to `strtod()` will begin conversion at `nptr` converting the ASCII floating-point value to `double` and it will update `endptr` to the next character after the last used in conversion. So you just loop calling `strtod()` (validating the conversion) and then update `nptr = endptr;` to set up for the next call. That way you work through the string converting all floats, no matter how many you have.

Comment: Here is an uncommonly long answer showing the use of `strtol()` (which is essentially the same as `strtod()` but also requires the number base). The final example reads with `fgets()` and converts as many ASCII integer values as are found to `int`. You are doing the same thing with `float` (there is a specific `strtof()` function if your type is `float`). They all work the same way. [strtol() example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800654/3422102)

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `while(i<=file_string[i])`. As that array holds `char` elemets, you can never get past element `255` of your `50000` byte array. Assuming you read pain text, you will stop even earlier. Is that supposed to be some weird way to detect the terminating `0` byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `strtod()` (for `double`) or `strtof()` (for `float`) is the correct approach for the conversion, and can be used to work through all values in each line read, there actually is a simpler way to approach this problem. Since the sets of ASCII characters (tokens) to be converted to floating-point values are all separated by one or more spaces, you can simply use `strtok()` to split the line read into `file_string` into tokens and then convert each token with `strtod()` (or `strtof()`)

What that does is simplify error handling and you having to increment the pointer returned in `endptr` past any characters not used in a conversion. If you process the entire line with `strtod()`, then for your `12e` or `4e.3` examples of bad values, it would be up to you to check if `endptr` pointed to something other than a space (one after the last char used in the conversion), and if that was the case, you would have to manually loop incrementing `endptr` checking for the next space.

When you tokenize the line with `strtok()` splitting all space separated words in `file_string` into tokens, then you only have to worry about validating the conversion and checking if `endptr` is pointing at something other than the `'\0'` (nul-terminating character) at the end of the token to know if the value was bad.

A quick example of doing it this way could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   /* for strtod()  */
#include <string.h>   /* for strtok()  */
#include <errno.h>    /* for errno     */
#include <ctype.h>    /* for isspace() */

#define DELIM " \t\n" /* delmiters to split line into tokens */

int main (void) {

  char file_string[] = "-123.45 1.2e7 boo 1.3e-7 12e 4e.3 1.1 2.22\n",
       *nptr = file_string,       /* nptr for strtod */
       *endptr = nptr;            /* endptr for strtod */
  size_t n = 0;
  
  nptr = strtok (file_string, DELIM);     /* get 1st token */
  
  while (nptr != NULL) {
    errno = 0;                            /* reset errno 0 */
    
    double d = strtod (nptr, &endptr);    /* call strtod() */
    
    printf ("\ntoken: '%s'\n", nptr);     /* output token (optional) */
    
    /* validate conversion */
    if (d == 0 && endptr == nptr) { /* no characters converted */
      fprintf (stderr, "error, no characters converted in '%s'.\n", nptr);
      d = -1000;        /* set bad value */
    }
    else if (errno) {   /* underflow or overflow in conversion */
      fprintf (stderr, "error: overflow or underflow converting '%s'.\n", 
                nptr);
      d = -1000;        /* set bad value */
    }
    else if (*endptr) { /* not all characters used in converison */
      fprintf (stderr, "error: malformed value '%s'.\n", nptr);
      d = -1000;        /* set bad value */
    }
    
    printf ("double[%2zu]: %g\n", n, d);  /* output double */
    n += 1;           /* increment n */
    
    nptr = strtok (NULL, DELIM);    /* get next token */
  }
}
```

(**note:** the string you pass to `strtok()`, e.g. `file_string` in your case cannot be a read-only *String-Literal* because `strtok()` modifies the original string. You can make a copy of the string if you need to preserve the original)

**Example Use/Output**

With `file_string` containing `"-123.45 1.2e7 boo 1.3e-7 12e 4e.3 1.1 2.22\n"`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/strtod_strtok_loop

token: '-123.45'
double[ 0]: -123.45

token: '1.2e7'
double[ 1]: 1.2e+07

token: 'boo'
error, no characters converted in 'boo'.
double[ 2]: -1000

token: '1.3e-7'
double[ 3]: 1.3e-07

token: '12e'
error: malformed value '12e'.
double[ 4]: -1000

token: '4e.3'
error: malformed value '4e.3'.
double[ 5]: -1000

token: '1.1'
double[ 6]: 1.1

token: '2.22'
double[ 7]: 2.22
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.